# Jupyter Notebook has problem to execute code in cell and it says ' UserWarning: Parent poll failed. '

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Im beginner in learning python, i started last week, and now i have a problem that i dont know how to solve.
Jupyter Notebook doesnt execute code in cell and this appears :

> "C:\Users\Davidvc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\parentpoller.py:116:
>   UserWarning: Parent poll failed.  If the frontend dies,
>     the kernel may be left running.  Please let us know
>     about your system (bitness, Python, etc.) at
>      ipython-dev@scipy.org
>      ipython-dev@scipy.org""") :

I dont understand what does it means, and how I can solve this. Is this has to do something with my antivirus?
Thanks

Comment: By what I read [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8205), it seems like a python 3.7 issue. Try changing to 3.6 and see if it keeps happening

Comment: Before I saw this i tried to uninstall, and then install again the same verson, and now it seems to work without problem. But if this happens again i will replace it for the 3.6 version. Thanks for answer.